# My Insert Stored Procedure works, but I get this error ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'

Tags: asp-classic, ado

This site has been very useful in helping resolved many unknowns. Thank you. Now I have one unknown that I have not been able to locate an answer to.

The error is:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
>
> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

I’m using:

- ASP Classic
- MS SQL Server 2000

In ASP there is a `<textarea>` within a “form” to insert notes, when notes are inserted and the submit button is pushed the stored procedure insert the note into the note table datetimestamp it and add the logon user. That is doing exactly what it is to do. Additionally in ASP there is a `<table>` that populates with the note, datetimestamp and logon user with the other previous entries. That also is doing exactly what it is to do.

The above mentioned error occurs when the submit button is pressed, by hitting the browsers back button when the error page shows up, then refreshing the page the `<textarea>` is cleared and note, datetimetime, and logon user display in the `<table>`

ASP Classic page:

```
Dim rsAccountNote

<form name="Accountnote" method="post" action="/admin/xt_Accountnote.asp">


    <td>
    <b>Add Note:</b><br />
    <textarea type="text" name="notes" value="" rows="7" cols="43" style="resize: none;"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add new note"/>
</td>

<table>

<tr>    

    <td>
    <b>Read Notes:</b>
    </td>

</tr>

        <%

        set rsAccountNote = DBConn.Execute("SELECT AccountNotes, LogonUser_Id, dtAccountNotedatetime FROM AccountNotes WHERE AccountId = " & rsAccount("AccountId"))

        rsAccountNote.Sort="dtAccountNotedatetime DESC" 

        Do While Not rsAccountNote.EOF

        %>          

<tr>

    <td>
    Added &nbsp;<%=rsAccountNote("dtAccountNotedatetime")%> &nbsp;by &nbsp;<%=rsAccountNote("LogonUser_Id")%>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td>
    <b>Note:&nbsp;</b> <%=rsAccountNote("AccountNotes")%>
    </td>

    </tr>

        <%

        rsAccountNote.MoveNext  

        Loop    

        Set rsAccountNote = Nothing

        %>

</tr>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

---

ASP Classic xt_page:

```
<%

Dim rsAccount
Dim iAccount
Dim LogonUser_id
Dim AccountNotes

sSQL = "exec spApp_UpdateAccountNotes " & _
    "@iAccount = " & Trim(Request("Account_id")) & ", " & _
    "@AccountNotes = " & prepString(Request("AccountNotes")) & ", " & _
    "@LogonUser_id = " & prepString(Request("Logon_User"))
Call resultQuery(DBConn, rsAccount, sSQL, "", true)

    Response.Redirect("/Account_admin/accountinfo.asp?account_id=" & Trim(Request("account_id")))

%>
```

---

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spApp_UpdateAccountNotes
    (
    @iAccount int,
    @LogonUser_id varchar (50),
    @AccountNotes varchar(5000)
    )
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    insert AccountNotes
        (
        AccountId,
        LogonUser_Id,
        AccountNotes
        )
    values
        (
        @iAccount,
        @LogonUser_Id,
        @AccountNotes
        )
GO
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Command object to execute the SP as parameterised query.  This solves the more serious problem of your code being open to a SQL Injection attack.

In fact your first page is also open to attack, you should use a command object there also.

Possibly the real source of your problem is that `resultQuery` tries to generate and do something with a recordset from the SP which doesn't return a result set, its only an insert.  Perhaps `resultQuery` just isn't the thing to call in this case.  An ADODB Command object and `Execute` would be all that is needed.

Comment: Anthony – thank you for your help. I’m not knowledgeable enough, yet, to know what an ADODB Command object and Execute would look like, but wanted to let you know I’ve read your reply and am on it, to try it.